# Construct a function from data experiment with more than one variable

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

Data fitting methods are mostly taught to construct a function with two data features, hence the function which is generated only one variable, $f(x)$. Are there any methods to construct a function with more than two variables (e.g.: $g(x,y,...)$) in numerical methods from experiment data?

Comment: The method of Least Squares Method can be applied with more than one independent variable.

Comment: Is the least square included tensor in its methods? Because two or more variables should have considered the 'shift' xy variable, isn't it?

Comment: It is a rather ill-posed task, meaning if you formulate it as linear fitting problem you are very likely to encounter an ill-conditioned matrix. The result will have reliable values only in the convex hull of the data points $(x_k,y_k)$, extrapolation is very much depending on the basis functions of the linear model. Artificial Neuronal Networks try to solve this task in a generalist manner, but with the same problems.